# What is the function rem_pio2f() used by GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, ieee-754, trigonometry

Examining the compiled code of the `sinf()` on our GCC implementation, I see that it calls a builtin function `___ieee754_rem_pio2f`. I tried searching for a clue on what this function is, but all I found were posts referring to a bug with the `rem_pio2f` (no `__ieee754`) function, with no explanation.

Can anyone shed some light on this function?

(sounds like "remainder of PI-over-2-float, or sth like that - but why need a function for a constant?)

EDIT: Thanks to @Thiruvalluvar for providing the source code:

`/* __ieee754_rem_pio2f(x,y)

 *

 * return the remainder of x rem pi/2 in y[0]+y[1]

 * use __kernel_rem_pio2f()

 */`

Comment: ieee 754 is the standard for floating point numbers, so it's likely a function that works with that format, prefixing with `iee754_` stresses this fact; if you've googled it, you've found pages where it is clear that it is not a constant, like this http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-i386/2005-February/002103.html

Comment: Thanks, @ShinTakezou. Yes I am well aware of what IEEE754 is. And I did see this page an similar other pages, but unfortunately it looks more like a SVN diff report than the full function code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sinf takes a float and returns a float. The support for floating point arithmetic was added in C99. The earlier C standards did't have sinf but only sin (which is for double). The ieee_754 indicates that the function is added to support floating point support. Here's a [source code](ftp://ftp.irisa.fr/pub/OpenBSD/src/lib/libm/src/e_rem_pio2f.c) link for the that file if are interested.

Comment: Thanks, @Thiruvalluvar. The answer is in the function's inline documentation - `/* __ieee754_rem_pio2f(x,y)
 * 
 * return the remainder of x rem pi/2 in y[0]+y[1] 
 * use __kernel_rem_pio2f()
 */
`